# Restrict access to Kibana using nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, kibana-4

I have a kibana dashboard which has visualizations about 100 employees which drills down to each employee based on his name.
Is there a way for Nginx to convert a request for the kibana dashboard into a dynamic URL and then proxy it to the kibana server.The URL is in the format `localhost:5601/#/dashboard/…;*',key:name,negate:!f,value:torres),query:(match:(name:(‌​query:torres,type:phrase)))))`.
Now if someone copies the above URL and changes the name value from torres to xyz, he can see data about xyz. So i need a dynamic url that is generated and contains the `'name'`  parameter which will be passed according to his login. I don't want any external client to access the dashboard directly by giving the URL above
Is it possible?